# Git HTTPS Authentication fails interactively, but works in the URL

Tags: linux, git, authentication, https, gitlab

When attempting to perform a `git clone https://gitlab.com/user/repo.git`, or `git clone https://USER@gitlab.com/user/repo.git` I get the error "fatal: Authentication failed"

When I do the same thing, but place the password in the URL (`git clone https://USER:PASS@gitlab.com/username/repo.git` the command works fine.

I'm looking for help on how to investigate what the difference is between these two operations.

I've tried (without success):

- `git config --global credential.https://gitlab.com.username USER`
- `git config --global https.sslverify false`
- With and without `SSH_ASKPASS` set to `/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass`
- Typing the password into the interactive prompt very carefully (obviously)

essentially, the interactive password prompt is failing for some reason I can't discover. Any help is appreciated.

This is on a work machine I don't have much control over, so I have to use HTTPS. I am also behind a proxy, but I don't have this problem with other tools (HTTPS_PROXY is set correctly). My machine details are:

- git 1.8.2.1
- RHEL 5.11 (Tikanga)
- `uname -srio` Linux 2.6.18-400.1.1.el5 x86_64 GNU/Linux